# jQuery Ajax Call return 404 - Version 3.5.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot, firefox

The ajaxCall function is returned 404 in the onChange select event. I've an aplication Spring Boot + BootStrap + Thymleaf + jQuery 3.5.1.

The URL parameter is the internal spring boot @RequesteMapping.

ERRO:

[image]

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 GET http://10.21.18.128:8080/carregaComboAtivoCadastraCampo?uoId=06ec619f-6ed6-469a-8318-9722da71bda0 404
send @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
carregaComboAtivoAjax @ funcoes.js:3
onchange @ cadCadastraCampo:42
ListPicker._handleMouseUp
```

The jQuery function:

The url function parameter is /carregaComboAtivoCadastraCampo?uoId=06ec619f-6ed6-469a-8318-9722da71bda0;

```
function carregaComboAtivoAjax(url) {
    var uoId = document.getElementById('idUo').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { uoId: uoId },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("body").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Spring Boot - Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carregaComboAtivoCadastraCampo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String carregaComboAtivo(@RequestParam UUID uoId,  Model model) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404, and the path is correct, then the issue is with your Spring routing configuration, not the client-side JS

Comment: It worked well using mysql db and a BigInt as a sequence type. I need to convert the db to Cassandra using spark and change the sequence type for UUID. Before these change, stop work. In the spring routing, I use @RequestMapping.

Comment: I checked my spring routing and it's ok. I noted that the problem happen in the server, after I prepare the .war file. Local host I don't have this problem. Could you have any idea? Obs.: I checked the @RequestMapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question by myself. I forgot to configurate the media type and the response body.

The solution is to put the tag @ResponseBody after the @RequestMapping and complicated the @RequestMapping the produce.

Controller code:

@RequestMapping(value = "/carregaComboAtivoCadastraCampo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView carregaComboAtivo(@RequestParam UUID uoId,  Model model) {
...
}